# How to clear screen and revert to menu? Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python 3 and I'm stuck at following.

I'm creating a Hangman Game for a School project and can't seem to clear the screen and revert back to the menu

Here is my code as shown below

```
import random
import os

WORDS = ["handkerchief", "accommodate", "indict", "impetuous"]
MAX_GUESSES = 7

print("^^^^^^^^^^THIS IS HANGMAN^^^^^^^^^^")

while True:

    input('Press <ENTER> to start a new game or <CTRL>+<C> to quit.')

    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    guess = ['_'] * len(word)
    guesses = set()
    n = MAX_GUESSES

    while True:

        print('\nYour word:', ' '.join(guess))
        print('You have {} chances left.'.format(n))

        if '_' not in guess:
            print('Congratulations, you win!\n')
            break

        if n < 1:
            print('Sorry, no guesses left. You lose!\n')
            break

        character = input('Guess a new character: ')

        if len(character) != 1:
            print('You must enter exactly one character!')


        if character in guesses:
            print('You have already guessed that character!')


        guesses.add(character)

        if character not in word:
            n -= 1


        for i, c in enumerate(word):
            if c == character:
                guess[i] = character

        os.system('clear')
        main()
```

Comment: How will this game be run? I believe that different environments have different ways to clear the screen, and some environments have no way at all to do so. Will the game be run in a DOS box (also called a CMD box) in Windows, or at the terminal in Python or in iPython or in an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), or in some other way?

Comment: On trinket.io as my school does not have notepad++ yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
```

Then you call `clear()` to clear the terminal at any time

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You stated in a comment that your environment is [trinket.io](https://trinket.io/). Trinket is meant for you to do programming, including in Python, from just about any computer and operating system. It is meant for beginners who are just learning to program.

I just did some web searching and I cannot find any way to clear the screen in `trinket.io`. Trinket is deliberately restricted, so you cannot get into serious trouble on your computer, but that protection is keeping you from doing some things like clearing the screen.

So do the traditional thing--the kind of thing I did when the only printout was on paper, which is not clear-able. When you want to clear the screen, instead print some blank lines so the user knows you are doing something different. Then reprint your menu. Printing 50 blank lines will almost certainly put your previous printing out of the user's view. Adjust that number of blank lines as you see fit.